# Github Action : How do I get access to Private repo from another organization?

Tags: git, workflow, github-actions, cicd

In the diagram below, I am trying to add a dependent private repo to my main repo. But that Private repo (**Org1/Private_repo**) is dependent on other organization private repo(**Org2/Private_repo**).

I am trying to CI/CD my process with GitHub action for my React Project to Firebase.

It works locally, though I have ssh setup on my machine and have a read access to (**Org2/Private_repo**).

But I don't know how to configure my .yml file for this scenario.

[image]

Here is My .yml file for pull request:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
"on": pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}"
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v2
     with:
      repository: Org1/Private_repo
      token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
      persist-credentials: false
    - run: git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf
        ssh://git@github.com/
    - run: npm ci && npm run build
    - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
      with:
        repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
        firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FIREBASE_PROJECT }}"
        projectId: firebaseProject
```

Comment: Did you add PAT_TOKEN to secrets in your settings ?...

Comment: Yes I did . under Secrets>Actions

Comment: Does it show any errors ? Can you share logs from the run ?

Comment: for the Org1/Private_repo its works as it is mentions in .yml but for Org2/Private_repo I am not sure how to add that . And the Error is something as npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'Org2/Private_repo.git'

Answer (score 0):

You would need to generate a second PAT from Org2 with the required scopes to access `Org2/Private_repo`, and also add it to the `Org1/Main_repo` secrets. Then reference this in the Firebase action `repoToken:`  field.

A PAT can only have scopes on the Organisation/account it is generated in, so your current PAT that is granting access to `Org1/Private_repo` doesn't grant access to Org2.

The `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` you are currently referencing in the Firebase action [only grants the Workflow scopes on the repo in which it is being run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token), and by default these are limited to read. So this will not be able to authenticate your Action to a repo in Org2.